# Streamline some jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to streamline some jQuery as it is taking too long to fire on some devices.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$( "#adultsPlus" ).click(function() {

    if($(".adults > select").val() != 9) {

        $(".adults > select").val(parseInt($(".adults > select").val())+1).change();

        $("#adultsCount").text($(".adults > select").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: On which devices does it take too long to fire?

Comment: Not related to taking too long, but parsing integers in *base 8* will probably lead to errors in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't exactly know why it takes too long on your devices, but obviously your code could be optimized to prevent frequent DOM searches of `$(".adults > select")`.

Something like:

```
$( "#adultsPlus" ).click(function() {
    var adults = $(".adults > select");
    var adultsValue = parseInt(adults.val());

    if(adultsValue != 9) {
        adultsValue++;
        adults.val(adultsValue).change();
        $("#adultsCount").text(adultsValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `$("#adultsCount").text(adultsValue - 1);`?

Comment: @jehna1 Hmm, I suppose it should not. Since this line `$(".adults > select").val(parseInt($(".adults > select").val())+1)` has changed value of `$(".adults > select")`, so argument of `$("#adultsCount").text` will be changed value. Am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately this is still causing lagging on iPhone 5S. On Xperia Z2 I seem to have no problem. If a user hits the button repeatedly it resets the JQuery and starts over, the desired effect being quick changes of #adultsCount, in time for the next button press..